# Express app.get not executing middleware function

Tags: express, middleware

I have an `app.get` call in my express.js app like this:

```
app.get('/blog', (query, res) => res.send('Hello Blog!'));
```

What I'm expecting to happen is that, every time someone goes to `example.com/blog`, function `query` is run, followed by `res`, which is just "Hello Blog!".

Further down the file, I have function `query`:

```
function query(req, res, next) {
  console.log('test');
  res.send('ploop!');
  next();
}
```

What I'm expecting here is to get something logged into my terminal window, followed by 'ploop!' getting logged to the window, and then `next()` should continue on with the original request. The `/blog` request goes through as expected, but `console.log('test');` and `res.send('ploop!);` don't appear to execute.

I realize `console.log` must not be the best way to troubleshoot/debug this situation in Node/Express. Ultimately, I'm trying to produce some kind of obvious output from function `query` that will let me know that it's working (or not working).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you declaring `app.use(query)` after you initialize your express server?

Comment: No. Do I need to do this for any functions I make that will be used for middleware?

Comment: @rpivovar Yes- that is how express knows to call your middleware function

Comment: Adding this made it work perfectly. Thanks for the help and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

To use that middleware you don't rename an argument like you have, you do the following:

```
app.get('/blog', query, (req, res) => res.send('Hello Blog!'));
```

It's passed as an argument to `app.get`.

Comment: Maybe I'm thinking about this the wrong way.. should I be trying to run functions from the `req` object? Can I add custom functions to `req`? (sorry if dumb questions)